# Dbpedia, optional tag trouble

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I'm having trouble getting the optional tag to return rows where some attributes may not exist. For example in the following query I return some information about the MMA fighter Lyoto Machida http://goo.gl/cWFk9N

```
SELECT ?surname ?givenName ?nick ?height ?born ?nationality ?birthplace

where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lyoto_Machida>   
 foaf:surname ?surname ;
 foaf:givenName ?givenName ;
 dbp:otherNames ?nick ;
 dbo:height ?height ;
 dbp:birthDate ?born ;
 dbp:nationality ?nationality ; 
 dbp:birthPlace ?birthplace  
}
```

Now if I want to use that same query, except with the MMA fighter Luke Rockhold I get no results. This is because he does not have a listed nationality or otherNames. So I tried using the optional tags around all my attributes but this still didn't work.

```
SELECT ?surname ?givenName ?nick ?height ?born ?nationality ?birthplace

where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Luke_Rockhold>   
 OPTIONAL {foaf:surname ?surname ;}
 OPTIONAL {foaf:givenName ?givenName ;}
 OPTIONAL {dbp:otherNames ?nick ;}
 OPTIONAL {dbo:height ?height ;}
 OPTIONAL {dbp:birthDate ?born ;}
 OPTIONAL {dbp:nationality ?nationality ; }
 OPTIONAL {dbp:birthPlace ?birthplace  }
}
```

Is there an error with my syntax or logic? I'm quite new to using sparql and dbpedia, any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't split a single pattern with `OPTIONAL` like that. The parts outside and inside `OPTIONAL` have to be valid patterns on their own. One way to do this would be to use `BIND`:

```
SELECT ?surname ?givenName ?nick ?height ?born ?nationality ?birthplace
WHERE {
 BIND(:Luke_Rockhold AS ?x)
 OPTIONAL {?x foaf:surname ?surname}
 OPTIONAL {?x foaf:givenName ?givenName}
 OPTIONAL {?x dbp:otherNames ?nick}
 OPTIONAL {?x dbo:height ?height}
 OPTIONAL {?x dbp:birthDate ?born}
 OPTIONAL {?x dbp:nationality ?nationality}
 OPTIONAL {?x dbp:birthPlace ?birthplace}
}
```